# How to put code into html for others to play in browser

Tags: python, html

I recently made a game that I enjoy playing, and so do my friends. After they download python for themselves, receive the .py files and then start playing. It's a hastle. I was wondering if there was anyway for me to take my game and all in it, put it in some .html that I host online, and have anyone play it whenever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to play a python game on a web page. Python is interpreted locally, on the user's computer. They have to download the files in order to play.

However, you can use a utility like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to make your game into an executable file, so it can run on its own without the user having to install python. (I'm assuming this is for Windows -- Macs already have Python installed).

**update**: Per Anderson Green's comment, putting [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) on your site will allow visitors to use python scripts in a web page.

Comment: It's also possible to run Python scripts directly in a web browser using [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/), so it certainly would be possible to develop client-side web-based Python games.

Comment: That's so useful! I'm glad to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of python you could look at packing it into an executable that would be easier to distribute. But unless there's some way of having your website be a persist ant virtual python environment, I don't think web hosting will be the way to go.

For python 2.x I know distutils is one method of packing an executable, but the last I checked, it wasn't compatible with 3.x.